# ¿se puede activar una ventana modal en una pasarela de pagos personalizada?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

amigos estoy buscando de activar una ventana modal dentro de una función php, específicamente en la función process_payment de una pasarela de pagos personalizada, pero no he logrado que se active la ventana modal al momento de que el banco aprueba el pago e imprimir el request dentro del modal.

lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

cree un archivo modal.php donde guardo el código del modal.

```
<?php
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

cree un archivo js llamado modal.js donde se activa el modal, código.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('open')
});
```

pero no sé como hacer que se active el modal dentro de la función process_payment de mi pasarela de pagos personalizada.

public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

```
           if (isset($response1->error_list)) {
                    
                    // $order->update_status('cancelled',__( 'Awaiting REDSYS payment', 'woocommerce-redsys' ));
                    wc_add_notice( __($response1->error_list[0]->description, 'woocommerce-payment'), 'error' );
                    return;
           }else{
        
                 // we received the payment
                $order->payment_complete();
                $order->reduce_order_stock();
            
            
                // Empty cart
                $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
            
                // Redirect to the thank you page
            
                return array(
                    'result' => 'success',
                    'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
                );
           }
```

}

hasta ahora con este código me carga el modal al momento de activar la pasarela, nunca queda oculto a pesar de que tiene ( aria-hidden="true" ) el modal se ve al cargar la pagina, pero, como les comento quiero que se active el modal antes de redireccionar a la pagina de gracias y poder imprimir el request dentro del modal.

mucho les agradezco me puedan ayudar. ya he intentado cada solución que he visto en la web y ninguno me ha funcionado.

muchas gracias...

Comment: El `aria-hidden="true"` no tiene ninguna injerencia en que se muestre o no el modal. Se muestra el modal al principio, porque así lo estas señalando aquí: `$( document ).ready`. Lo que no entiendo, es porque quieres mostrar un modal antes que la pagina se redireccione, no le veo el sentido, el modal se abrirá por un corto momento y luego la página se ira a la redirección sin dar tiempo en leer lo que dice

Comment: gracias yussef, quiero mostrar el modal porque tengo una variable que recibe el request del banco en formato json y contiene información de aprobación de la transacción y quiero mostrarla al cliente en pantalla para que luego lo redireccione a la pagina de gracias. No sé si en realidad se pueda hacer el modal en la pagina de gracias e imprimir el request o la variable en pantalla para que luego el cliente pueda imprimir o hacer un capture de pantalla de la transacción y con $( document ).ready es la función javascript porque en esta parte no hay botón para llamar al modal gracias nuevamente

Comment: he intentado capturar la variable en la pagina de gracias e imprimirlo pero, cuando lo hago la variable ya no se encuentra o no se imprime la data, entonces no sé como enviar la variable a la pagina de gracias cuando haga la redirección a la pagina de gracias

Comment: respuesta si se puede, en programacion se puede el 99% de las cosas.

Comment: a pesar que has agregado codigo de ejemplo sigo sin entender cual es el error esactamente, has evaluado los eventos de los modal para hacer una correcta implementacion de los mismos, en este punto es prioridad leer documentacion?

Comment: gracias arcanisGK507 el problema en si no es el modal, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: ¿Cómo hacer para que se active el modal dentro de una función php? específicamente en la function process_payment, no sé como abrir el modal desde allí y lo del modal que se muestra al cargar el plugin lo arregle mandando el script al final de la pagina. muchas gracias.